# Detect when Delete or Backspace keys are pressed with onKeyPress and not with onKeyUp in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to activate a function when the Delete or Backspace keys are pressed. The call is made inside a number input filed which is part of a form. This works:

```
onKeyUp={((e) => this.onCero(e))}
```

This does not work:

```
onKeyDown ={((e) => this.onCero(e))}
```

The function I am calling:

```
onCero = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.key === "Delete" || e.key === "Backspace") {
        alert(e.key);
    }
};
```

I need to trigger the function when the key is pressed, not when it is released using React or JavaScript.

Any ideas guys? Thanks.

Comment: Sidenote: `onCero` is already bound to the instance and has the signature of an event handler. No need to wrap it in another arrow-function. `onKeyDown={this.onCero}`. That way you don't change the props of the input *(at least not through this)*. Therefore less unnecessary updates

Comment: @Thomas, thanks mate, you are right. My intention is to run the function inside the onKey event. Just took it outside for testing, that is the reason of the arrow function there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the classic JavaScript's event listeners for that.

It would be something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onCero, false);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.onCero, false);
}
```

And then use can use the key codes in your onCero function:

```
onCero = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 27 || e.keyCode === 13) {
    alert(e.keyCode);
  }
};
```

Comment: I selected this approach because now I can use other event handlers like onChange or onInput from the <input type="number" /> if required, and still get this function triggered when needed. I just changed the values of the Keycodes to e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46 to match delete and backspace. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be working fine.

```js
class App extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
  super(props);
   }
      onCero = (e) => {
    console.log(e.key);
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.key === "Delete" || e.key === "Backspace") {
        alert(e.key);
    }
};
   render(){
  return(
   <input type="number" onKeyDown ={((e) => this.onCero(e))}  />
  )
   }
 }

 ReactDOM.render(
 <App/>,
 document.getElementById("root")
 );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call it via onKeyPress={this.onCero}. This should work